# automodule to generate toc in sphinx documents

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In Sphinx, is there a way to get the automodule directive to generate a TOC of the members in the class?

Right now I have

.. Contents::

```
.. topic:: Abstract

   bla bla bla

.. automodule:: ServerCommHandler
    :members:
    :private-members:
    :special-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :inherited-members:
```

which works fine, but this module has a lot of methods in it and a toc pointing to the method would be really nice.

Comment: I'm also interested in such a capability.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

How about [toctree](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/toctree.html).

```
.. toctree::

   ServerCommHandler
```

Comment: Sphinx complains: `WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'ServerCommHandler'` because the file is a Python module, not a ReST document.

Answer (score 7):

The [autodocsumm](https://github.com/Chilipp/autodocsumm) extension will allow autodoc directives (automodule, autoclass) to automatically add summary tables like those of the builtin autosummary extension.

It can be used as follows:

```sh
pip install autodocsumm
```

Then edit your `conf.py` to add the extension:

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    ...,
    'autodocsumm',
]
```

and add an `:autosummary:` option to your autodoc directives, e.g.:

```
.. automodule: foo.bar
    :autosummary:
```

If you want to have autosummary in effect for all your autodoc directives without explicitly adding them, you can do so from the `conf.py` as follows:

```py
autodoc_default_options = {
    'autosummary': True,
}
```

This is particularly helpful if you dynamically generate your API pages with sphinx-apidoc which is not easily configurable to add `:autosummary:`.

Full example of a `conf.py` that autogenerates all API pages:

```py
def setup(app):
    from sphinx.ext import apidoc
    app.connect('builder-inited', lambda _: apidoc.main([
        '-o', './api', '-d2', '-feMT', '../src/PROJECT',
    ]))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'autodocsumm',
]


autodoc_default_options = {
    'autosummary': True,
}

autodata_content = 'both'
```